# Laravel Eloquent when save or delete

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    $customer = customer::find($request->ID);

    $customer->delete();

}
Back Query
"delete from `customer` where `id` is null"
```

when using Laravel's eloquent, it returns back the query but why is `id` showing as `null`?

Comment: Are you sure `$request->ID` is actually populated? do `dd($request->ID)` and see what shows

Comment: yes working http://imgur.com/OS9TXUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the problem edit Primary key on model because on database is primary key is "ID" not "id"

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `$request->id`. So, do this:

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    Customer::destroy($request->id);
}
```

Or:

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    Customer::where('id', $request->id)->delete();
}
```

Comment: I can do this but why id null

Comment: @MahmoudGad `dd($request->id)` shows `null`? If so, please show the form code.

Comment: Is it because OP is using `ID` instead of `id`? Do you need to tell Laravel to query a different column from what it's expecting to look for?

Answer (score 1):

let's try this

it will work

```
customer::where('id', $request->ID)->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to code like this.

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
Customer::where('id', $request->input('ID'))->delete();
```

}